# Java garbage collector fails to clean up memory while loading ontology files

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am facing the issue of **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** in my application every time I try to load and process a bunch of **.owl** files. I have 500 odd .owl files in a directory and I load them one by one into memory using the `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument()` method of OWL API inside a `for` loop. However, after the method loads a few ontologies, the memory starts getting exhausted. The unused object references are not getting cleaned up by the garbage collector. I googled the problem and used **-Xmx** to increase the heap size upto 5GB suggested by many . But the problem still persists. I appreciate any help in this regard.

```
OWLOntologyManager owlManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); 
File folder = new File("G:\\OWL and OBO");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        try{
            File sourceFile = new File( "G:\\OWL and OBO\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            OWLOntology ontology = owlManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(sourceFile);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 5gb is not something a jvm will really accept. try to use 1024, 2048 and more. my experience is, that 4k should never be overcome to work

Comment: 5gb or any other number will work, it does not have to be a standard 2^n number. However, your code ( or the `OWLOntologyManager` ) might actually be using that memory. What is the size of files & how many files do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that the OWLOntologyManager is hanging on to some memory between files.  Have you tried moving that first line inside the listOfFiles loop?  It'll be 'more expensive' to create a new instance for each file, but that's better than 'broken'.

```
File folder = new File("G:\\OWL and OBO");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        OWLOntologyManager owlManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); 
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        try{
            File sourceFile = new File( "G:\\OWL and OBO\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            OWLOntology ontology = owlManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(sourceFile);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user8594397 The Javadoc says "An OWLOntologyManager also manages the mapping betweem an ontology and its ontology document". In order to *manage* such a mapping, then it has to keep all loaded data.